# If TestFlight pre-beta is past the expiration date, do I have to reupload the binary

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I've set up a TestFlight pre-beta on iTunes connect that's past the expiration date. Do I have to reupload the binary or can I invite another user to test it without doing that?

Answer (score 2):

I have tried it but I couldn't invite another user to test it without reuploading the binary.

[image]

You have to reupload new binary.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you always(if it is expired) need to submit a new binary with an incremented build number, if you want it to be reactivated for testing.